# delete lines from a file that are broken over multiple lines with "\"

Tags: regex, linux, bash, unix, sed

I want to delete lines from a file based on a string i am searching for, like this:

```
sed -i.bak '/xyz/d' "$PATH"
```

The Problem for me are the lines that contain that string and are broken over multiple lines with "\", like this:

```
this is the string im looking for xyz but there \
   are other lines \
   that are part \
   of that \
   god damn line
```

is there an easy way to delete the WHOLE "line" with bash/sed/regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could say:

```
sed -e :a -e '/.*xyz.*\\$/N; s/\\\n//; ta' -e '/xyz/d' filename
```

(This would join the line containing `xyz` that's split over multiple lines ending in `/` and then delete it.)

Comment: it seems to work :) i'll have to test it in different files to see if it works everywhere for me. And thanks for the explanation ;-)

Comment: What if the `xyz` was not on the first line of a multiple line? Does the OP want all multiple lines consolidated?

Comment: @potong Given the example I assumed that `xyz` was on the first line.  As always, your `sed` answers always present something to learn.  Honestly.

Comment: @potong in this case the search pattern was always in the first line ;-) but good to know how to do it, if it hasn't been that way!

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;/\\$/{N;ba};h;s/\\\n//g;/xyz/d;g' file
```

This gathers up multiple lines, copies them to the hold space, removes the split line markers and then deletes the whole line if it contains `xyz`. If the line does not contain `xyz` the orginal split lines are replaced and printed out.

If it is preferred that all multiple lines are consolidated regardless, then:

```
sed ':a;/\\$/{N;ba};s/\s*\\\n\s*/ /g;/xyz/d' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Because sed operates one line at a time, you will need to use the `N` command to join the lines.

This post explains the usage quite well: [How the 'N' command works in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255796/how-the-n-command-works-in-sed)