# While using sed, how to remove \n with \t if a line ends with number

Tags: bash, vim, awk, sed

I have a file which contains lines ending with letters and lines ending with numbers. For example,

```
Integral ionization cross-section for |K| = 0.60
-5.591955866599557e-15  -7.944431558483296e-17i
```

The first line ends with a number and the second one with a letter.
What I'd like to do is, if a line ends with the number remove \n and insert \t in it's place.

But I can't figure out how to do so in sed. I tried using `sed -i 's/[0-9]\n/\t/'`, but it changes the number as well. Is it possible to leave the number unchanged and just change the end of line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using GNU `sed`:

```
sed -Ez 's/([0-9])\n/\1\t/g' file.txt
```

`-z` will cause the input to be treated as NUL separated instead of (default) newline separated.

**Example:**

```
% cat foo.txt
Integral ionization cross-section for |K| = 0.60
-5.591955866599557e-15  -7.944431558483296e-17i
Integral ionization cross-section for |K| = 0.60
-5.591955866599557e-15  -7.944431558483296e-17i

% sed -Ez 's/([0-9])\n/\1\t/g' foo.txt
Integral ionization cross-section for |K| = 0.60    -5.591955866599557e-15  -7.944431558483296e-17i
Integral ionization cross-section for |K| = 0.60    -5.591955866599557e-15  -7.944431558483296e-17i
```

Answer (score 3):

With `sed`:

```
sed '/[0-9]$/ { N; s/\n/\t/; }'
```

Output:

```
Integral ionization cross-section for |K| = 0.60        -5.591955866599557e-15  -7.944431558483296e-17i
```

To handle consecutive lines that end in number, try this:

```
sed ':l; /[0-9]$/ { N; s/\n/\t/; bl; }' test.txt
```

With Vim:

```
:%s/\d\zs\n/\t/g
```

With `awk`:

```
awk '{ while($0 ~ /[0-9]$/) { getline n; $0 = $0 "\t" n } } 1' test.txt
```

With `perl`:

```
perl -00pe 's/\d\K\n/\t/gs' test.txt
```

Comment: There is a catch. If 2 consecutive lines end with a number, only one of them will be joined to next line with a tab.

Comment: @anishsane If that's your reading of the question, than sure.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use Perl for this kind of thing:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=\d)\n$/\t/;' <file;
## Integral ionization cross-section for |K| = 0.60        -5.591955866599557e-15  -7.944431558483296e-17i
```

Answer (score 1):

sed is for simple substitutions on single lines so a sed solution will be unclear and/or non-portable and/or inefficient and/or fragile. Here's an awk solution that is none of those things:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s", $0, (/[0-9]$/ ? "\t" : "\n")}' file
Integral ionization cross-section for |K| = 0.60        -5.591955866599557e-15  -7.944431558483296e-17i
```

or if you prefer brevity over clarity:

```
$ awk '{ORS=(/[0-9]$/?"\t":"\n")}1' file
Integral ionization cross-section for |K| = 0.60        -5.591955866599557e-15  -7.944431558483296e-17i
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you could do it with `sed`:

```
$ sed -i 'N;s/\n/\t/' filename
```

The `N` command is the trick that makes it possible to match newline characters.

See [this answer on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255796/how-the-n-command-works-in-sed) for an explanation of `N`.

Comment: replace `\n` with `\t` **if a line ends with number**

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r ':a;N;s/([0-9])\n/\1\t/;ta;P;D' file
```

This reads two lines at a time and then having replaced a number followed by a newline with a number followed by a tab, tops up the pattern space with another line and repeats. If the substitution does not take place the first line is printed then deleted and another appended.