# How to find and replace \n to ', '

Tags: linux, bash, text, sed, tr

I have the text file with the column of the numbers, that I need to transform to the line with the numbers separated by ', '

For example:

```
$ cat file.txt
1034008
1034043
10340431
1034051
```

Then I use `tr`:

```
tr "\n" "', '" < file.txt > file2.txt
```

But, result is:

```
$ cat file2.txt
1034008'1034043'10340431'1034051
```

So, what I need to do to get the correct result?

Comment: please also add complete expected output for clarity.. not sure if you need quotes as well in output

Comment: `tr "\n" "," < file`

Answer (score 5):

`tr` can only to one-to-one mapping, not one-to-many

```
$ # convert all input lines to one line
$ # using , as separator, cannot give multiple character separator
$ paste -sd, ip.txt
1034008,1034043,10340431,1034051

$ # post process it
$ paste -sd, ip.txt | sed 's/,/, /g'
1034008, 1034043, 10340431, 1034051

$ # or use a tool that allows input record separator manipulation
$ perl -pe 's/\n/, / unless eof' ip.txt
1034008, 1034043, 10340431, 1034051
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
Now I'm see where was my misconception.

Answer (score 0):

1.We can do this by sed.
The command `N` of sed can reads the next line into pattern space.So we use `N` to merge 2 lines into 1.But how to merge all lines into one?
We can set a lebel  at the beginning and use `t label` to jump to the lebel to make a loop.

`$ sed ':myLebel;N;s/\n/, /; t myLebel; ' file.txt  > file2.txt
$ cat file2.txt 
1034008, 1034043, 10340431, 1034051`

2.In your question, we can use `xargs` to read all content into one line which is delimited by space,and then use `sed` to replace space to the strings you want.

`$ cat file.txt | xargs |sed 's/ /, /g' > file2.txt
$ cat file2.txt 
1034008, 1034043, 10340431, 1034051`

Refer to:
[How the 'N' command works in sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255796/how-the-n-command-works-in-sed)
https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/12/unix-sed-tutorial-6-examples-for-sed-branching-operation/

Comment: While this code could solve the problem, it is best to add elaboration and explain how it works for people who might not understand this piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

pure bash, to avoid external commands (faster)

```
tk="$(< file.txt)"
echo "${tk//$'\n'/, }" > file2.txt
```