# Understand N command with sed

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am trying to edit a file with some IPs.

There is an empty line at the end of the file.
I have multiples workers (XXXX, YYYY, ZZZZ and others). They all have two network interface in my file (ens192 & ens224). Each cni have one IP (ip192 for the cni ens192, and ip224+[worker number] for ens224)

My goal is to add ens256 after each ip224 with one sed command, but I'm struggling to understand how sed works.
Can someone explain why is sed is doing this:

```
> cat file
workerXXXX
ens192
ip192
ens224
ip2241

workerYYYY
ens192
ip192
ens224
ip2242

workerZZZZ
ens192
ip192
ens224
ip2243

> sed -n '{N; /^ens224\s/{p}}' file
>
```

No output!

But if I edit the file:

```
> cat file
workerXXXX
ens192
ip192
ens224
ip2241
randomelinehere

workerYYYY
ens192
ip192
ens224
ip2242

workerZZZZ
ens192
ip192
ens224
ip2243

> sed -n '{N; /^ens224\s/{p}}' file
ens224
ip2242
ens224
ip2243
```

**Why is sed printing lines here and not before?
Why is it only printing line after it reaches 'randomlinehere' ?**

I have found that if I add a 'D' at the end, everything work as expected (without the randomlinehere)
`sed -n '{N; /^ens224\s/{p}; D}' file`
And I think I'm close to what I need. (I just need to add 'ens256' after I find my pattern, but for now the 'a' is consuming the closing bracket with `sed -n '{N; /^ens224\s/{a ens256}; D}' file`)

---

EDIT:

My goal was to do this:

```
workerXXXX
ens192
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
ens224
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

↓

```
workerXXXX
ens192
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
ens224
XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
ens256
```

With sed because I wanted to learn more about this command.
I encountered a weird behavior with the `\N` command, that's why I asked this question.

The 'ip224' is random, so I cannot use `sed '/ip224/a ens256'`
The goal is to add text (`ens256`) two line after a pattern (`ens224`)

Comment: Perhaps reading [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#advanced-sed) will throw some light on your problem. BTW when asking a question like this put yourself in the other persons shoes - you've shown your input file but not what you expect the result to look like.

Comment: Why not append the text like `sed '/^ip224/a ens256' file`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255796/what-does-the-n-command-do-in-sed

Comment: In general, any time you're using constructs other than s, g, and p (with -n) in sed you'd be better off using awk for some combination of clarity, simplicity, robustness, efficiency, portability, etc. sed has a ton of constructs that were necessary when it was first invented but became obsolete literally about half a century ago when awk was also invented. Once you accept an answer to this question, if you ask a new question and show the expected output we can help you do what you want without having to get into the arcane incantations required by sed to do it.

Comment: Thanks potong , that is what I want: to learn more about sed.
Thefourthbird , I edited my post. ip224 is random, I cannot use it in the pattern search.
Orion , with the link potong provided, I think I understand my problem now.
EdMorton , Yes, I have found a lot of answer using awk. I will learn that tool a bit later.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed -n '{N; /^ens224\s/{p}}'` file does not print anything, because `\N` pulls the next line into the pattern space, so you test the pattern against 2 lines with a newline in between.

For the first example data, the line in the pattern space looks for example like `ip192\nens224`

The string `ens224` is not at the start of the line, to the `^` does not match, and the `\s` at the end can not match a whitespace char.

If you add `randomelinehere`, then pulling the next line in the pattern space will now have `ens224` at the beginning of the line for the last 2 occurrences .

The line after the addition of the extra line now looks like `ens224\nip2242` and that is why you see 2 times 2 lines printed in your question.

---

What you might do is match the line starting with  `ens224` and then append the text:

```
sed '/^ip224/a ens256' file
```

Or if you want to append a line to the match only:

```
sed -n '/^ip224.*/{s//&\nens256/p}' file
```

Comment: I edited my question: 'ip224' is random, so I cannot use it in the pattern search.

Thanks you a lot for the first part, I now understand way more the `\N`: "randomlines" changes even & odd lines. So my search is working.

Comment: @Lukyky414 `My goal is to add ens256 after each ip224`